# Changing the data type of id column

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I'm trying to update the data type of the `id` column from `public.profiles` table within `supabase`. i've been running this command:

```
ALTER TABLE public.profiles
ALTER COLUMN id type uuid_generate_v4();
```

then run `supabase db reset` to see the changes in local db but send me back an error

```
Error: ERROR: identity column type must be smallint, integer, or bigint (SQLSTATE 22023)
At statement 0: ALTER TABLE public.profiles       
ALTER COLUMN id set data type uuid
```

In local db with `supabase` i have activated the extension `uuid-ossp`

Comment: The error message has the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first [drop the `IDENTITY` attribute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) from the column.
Then change the data type to `uuid`, providing a translation expression from `int` -> `uuid`. I chose `md5(id::text)::uuid`. See:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)

Then set the default to `uuid_generate_v4()` - the additional module `"uuid-ossp"` must be installed for that, obviously.

`DROP IDENTITY` must go first. The rest can be done in a single command. Best do it all in a single transaction.

```sql
ALTER TABLE profiles ALTER COLUMN id DROP IDENTITY IF EXISTS;

ALTER TABLE profiles
  ALTER COLUMN id type uuid USING md5(id::text)::uuid
, ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FCygkC2r)

Rewrites the whole table. So you may want to run `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` to remove bloat afterwards (and clean up other stuff).

If `id` is also the PK, that's adapted automatically.
Alternatively, drop the column `id` and add a new one. Would be cheaper for big tables. The new column is appended at the end of the table, though.

Or create a copy of the table, switching out the `id` column in the process. If you can afford that.